# Facebook connect iframe applications and ie6 fb:friend-selector

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer-6, facebook

This is one of two scripts I'm having problems with involving the fb:friend-selector. It's a facebook iframe application but no matter what I try, in ie6 the height is around 150px which gives scrollbars. By adding 1px borders it would seem that in other browsers where it does actually work, there is an initial height of around 150px whci hresizes as the friends list gets populated. In IE6 this never happens.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head></head> 

<body> 

    <script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" type="text/javascript"></script> 

    <?=$_GET[friend_sel];?>

    <fb:serverfbml style="width: 500px; height:20px; border:1px solid red">

        <script type="text/fbml">

        <form id="addform" action="http://www.keywordintellect.com/facebook/iframeexample/serverfbml.php?<?=fbvars?>">
            <fb:fbml>
                <fb:friend-selector uid="<?=$user_id?>" name="newuid" idname="friend_sel" style="height: 700px"></fb:friend-selector>
            </fb:fbml>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>

        </script>
    </fb:serverfbml>

<script src="http://static.ak.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
    FB_RequireFeatures(["XFBML"], function(){ 
    FB.Facebook.init("<?php echo $appapikey ?>", "xd_receiver.htm",null);
    FB.CanvasClient.startTimerToSizeToContent(); 
    }
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set up your applicaion IFrame Size to Resizable?
if you don't go to your application ->edit setting->canvas->canvas setting->IFrame Size
the check Resizable.